Indexer does not recognize fields for mapping
Dears, good morning.
I have a problem creating the indexer and index in my search service.
I have a folder with several JSON files inside the azure blob, the json structure is as follows:
{
    "modelo": "55uq7950psb",
    "caracteristicas": {
        "Processador": "Processador AI a5 Ger5 4K",
    }
}

When I create my indexer I try to map the field but the index remains null, generating only the hash of the field that I defined as key, below the code structure I am using
index: I created an id field as key and a string field as
indexer:
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "caracteristicas",
      "targetFieldName": "caracteristicas",
      "mappingFunction": null
    }
  ],

I already tried to do it in the automatic way that the search service panel has, but then the structure looks like this image attached

all text is contained in a single field "chunk"
If anyone can help me, thank you very much
I would like the index to store each field of my json in an individual field to optimize searches and speed, the way I managed to store all information within the chunk field

To index JSON documents with each field stored individually, including the chunk field for optimized searches, we can use the Text Split skill according to this document from Chunk in vector search - Azure AI Search.
Sample index:
Change it according to the input field:
{
  "name": "myIndex",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false },
    { "name": "title", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true },
    { "name": "author", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true },
    // Define other fields here as needed
    { "name": "chunk", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "filterable": false }
  ]
}

Skillset:
"skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
      "textSplitMode": "pages",
      "maximumPageLength": 1000,
      "pageOverlapLength": 100,
      "maximumPagesToTake": 1,
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        },
        {
          "name": "languageCode",
          "source": "/document/language"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "textItems",
          "targetName": "mypages"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]



Change the Indexers according to skill add.

Alternatively, I followed this link to see data chunking using LangChain's Recursive Character Text Splitter with Python.
Setup Search Index for Recursive Text Splitter:
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient
from lib.common import create_search_index

search_index_client = SearchIndexClient(endpoint=search_endpoint, credential=search_credential)
rts_searchindex = create_search_index(
    recursivetextsplitter_searchindex,
    azure_openai_endpoint,
    azure_openai_embedding_deployment_id,
    azure_openai_key
)
search_index_client.create_or_update_index(rts_searchindex)

print("Created recursive text splitter index")

Initialize Recursive Text Splitter:
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from lib.common import get_encoding_name

recursive_text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter.from_tiktoken_encoder(
    encoding_name=get_encoding_name(),
    chunk_size=600, 
    chunk_overlap=125
)

Azure AI Search text splitter data chunking example
(Or)
Use this link to use Kernel Memory to Chunk Documents into Azure AI Search with C#.
